# Flutter won't rebuild a text

Tags: flutter

In my app, I have some (youtube)links, which always have the text value of "Link", but their tap launch parameter is different as the content of the page is changing.

I recognized that the app first builds these links with the initial correct value, then, upon changes, they won't get updated.

```
  RichText _createExerciseLink(String url) {
    return new RichText(
      text: new TextSpan(
        children: [
          new TextSpan(
            text: Translate.of(context).trans("exercise.link"),
        
            recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                print("Launcihng: ${url}");
                launch(url);
              },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But, if I change the text "link" to the corresponding HTTP link then it gets rerendered...

```
  RichText _createExerciseLink(String url) {
    return new RichText(
      text: new TextSpan(
        children: [
          new TextSpan(
            text: url,
   
            recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                print("Launcihng: ${url}");
                launch(url);
              },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I assume this is some kind of a caching mechanism?

Is there any way to force to recreate the whole widget?

Comment: did my suggestion help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like adding a `Key` is the trick here:

Parent widget:

```
            Key key = new Key(link);
               ...
            link != null ? _createExerciseLink(link, key) : Container(),
```

and in the text:

```
  RichText _createExerciseLink(String url, Key key) {
    return new RichText(
      key: key,
      text: new TextSpan(
        children: [
          new TextSpan(
            text: Translate.of(context).trans("exercise.link"),

            recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () {
                print("Launcihng: ${url}");
                launch(url);
              },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```